# Starting an android emulator

Tags: android, cordova

I'm running OSX 10.10.3

I'm trying to make an AVD but am having issues.
I followed these instructions http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds-cmdline.html and http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide

I run

```
$ android create avd -n first -t 2 --abi default/x86
Android 5.1.1 is a basic Android platform.
Do you wish to create a custom hardware profile [no]
Error: Unable to find a 'userdata.img' file for ABI x86 to copy into the AVD folder.
Error: AVD not created.
```

I have many sdks and images installed but for whatever reason the avd creation tools can't locate them. How do I fix this?[image: AVD screencap]

Here's what my sdk manger looks like [image: sdk manager screencap]

Comment: did you try to open Android SDK through eclipse IDE and create a new avd? This is kinda old, but it worths a try http://tech.thecoolblogs.com/2012/01/unable-to-find-userdataimg-file-for-abi.html

Comment: I could try that. But I have no interest in Eclipse. I need someone that knows what environment settings are needed/fixed.

Comment: Just try and if it works, the chances are that the modification eclipse did will be availabe outside of it and that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up deleting my sdk tools directory. Reinstalling the stand alone sdk-tools and android studio. Then the SDK manager redownloaded all the necessary images.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your answer is in the screenshot: "This AVD may not work unless you install the Google APIs Intel Atom system image for API 22 first."

You say you have "many sdks and images installed" but please verify that you have that one in question installed.

Also, you can try creating the avd with the armeabi system image instead of the x86 one.

Also, the Google APIs have a different system image than the "plain" SDK targets.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fp27ke4x0c9kirq/Screenshot%202015-05-29%2017.12.27.png?dl=0 I believe I have it installed

Answer (score 1):

Look your sdk manager image.

You must check:

- Intel x86 Atom_64 system image.
- Intel x86 Atom system image.

And create the AVD again.

Comment: that's for a different API level. I want to run API level 22 Android 5.1.1